# Como arrastar uma div na minha página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como posso implementar um drag e drop num `div` sem que esse elemento mexesse com outros elementos da minha página e ficasse por cima deles?

Também precisava que ele ficasse onde estava, anteriormente, se eu apertar <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: Você já tem uma estrutura básica do html para demonstrar ?

Comment: A pergunta em si é boa, mas está ampla, sem mesmo uma página de exemplo com a div que quer movimentar, por isso -1. Acho que seria possível fazer isso usando dados do x e y do mouse.

Comment: Tipo igual os cPanel da vida ? Que arrasta um bloco acima de outro ?

Comment: A sua pergunta já tem uma "resposta", mas não responde tudo. Faltou a parte do ESC para retornar. Se você adicionar uma forma de drag e drop na pergunta e alterar apenas para acrescentar o ESC, acho que ela poderá ser reaberta. Para falar a verdade, eu gostaria muito de responder ela apenas por essa parte do ESC. kk

Answer (score 7):

Há algum tempo eu desenvolvi esta função :

```js
function parseNumber(num) {
    return parseFloat(num.replace(/[^\d]/)) || 0;
}

var movePopUp = (function() {

    var startX;
    var startY;

    var currentPopUp = null;
    var currentWidth = 0;
    var currentHeight = 0;
    var currentLeft = 0;
    var currentTop = 0;
    var callMoveOnPopUp = null;
    var callMoveStopPopUp = null;

    var contentMove = '.popup .title';
    var move = false;

    var marginStop = 30;
    var maxWidth = window.innerWidth - marginStop;
    var maxHeight = window.innerHeight - marginStop;

    jQuery(contentMove).on('mousedown', function(e) {
        currentPopUp = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        currentLeft = parseNumber(currentPopUp.style.left);
        currentTop = parseNumber(currentPopUp.style.top);

        startX = e.clientX;
        startY = e.clientY;
        if (typeof(callMoveOnPopUp) == 'function')
            callMoveOnPopUp(currentPopUp);
        move = true;
    });

    jQuery(document).on('mouseup', function() {
        if (currentPopUp == null) return;
        if (typeof(callMoveStopPopUp) == 'function')
            callMoveStopPopUp(currentPopUp);
        currentPopUp = null;
        move = false;
    })

    jQuery(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if (move == true) {
            var newX = currentLeft + e.clientX - startX;
            var newY = currentTop + e.clientY - startY;

            if (marginStop > e.clientX) return;
            if (marginStop > e.clientY) return;
            if (maxWidth < e.clientX) return;
            if (maxHeight < e.clientY) return;

            jQuery(currentPopUp).css({
                'left': newX,
                'top': newY,
            });
        }
    });

    return function(func1, func2) {
        callMoveOnPopUp = func1;
        callMoveStopPopUp = func2;
    }
})();
```

```css
.popup{
    position : fixed;
    width : 250px;
    height : 200px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}

.popup .title{
  width: 240px;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #CCC;
  cursor : move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="popup" style="top:50px; left:50px;">
 <div class="popup_head">
  <div class="title">
   <span>TESTE DE POPUP</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="popup_body">
 </div>
</div>
```

O interessante dela é que possui margem limite e função `callback`, tanto quando o `popup` é clicado para arrastar, quanto quando para de ser arrastado.

Como cerca de 90% dele esta em JS puro, não seria complicado alterar os eventos no jQuery por eventos no JS puro.

#### Camada Callback

```
function callMoveOn(){
    console.log('on');
}

function callMoveStop(){
    console.log('stop');
}

movePopUp(callMoveOn, callMoveStop);
```

Caso queira explicações de funcionamento solicite.

Comment: Por que quando arrasta ele dá umas travadas ou para ?

Comment: @Zoom por causa da margem (`marginStop`), caso o usuário queira arrastar para fora da pagina, assim não conseguindo voltar com ela.